# OctoberCMS admin delete multiple photos from UI

Tags: php, octobercms

I have one quick question in OctoberCMS , if OctoberCMS provides this feature in admin backend in UI.

I have created plugin and added this field *Photos (png,jpg):* there.

**fields.yaml**

```
photos:

            label: 'Photos (png,jpg):'

            mode: image

            fileTypes: 'jpeg,jpg,png'

            useCaption: true

            thumbOptions:

                mode: crop

                extension: auto

            span: left

            required: 1

            type: fileupload

            tab: 'Property Information'
```

And here is the screenshot of this field how its looking like.

[image]

Plugin and functionality working fine. But I want an option if I can delete multiple images at once. Something like *Select All* checkbox and *Delete Button* and a Checkbox beside each photo. Currently I need to remove one after another.

I have researched and could not find any core solution from OctoberCMS side.

Is it possible ? or do I need to create a code and make a functionality altogether for this ? any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

core will not provide this things you need to develop at your own

> instead adding `partial` its wise to use `custom form widget` so you can use them else where also.

this guide will help you to build one

> https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/widgets#form-widgets (**Form Widgets Section**)

after that you can use it inside `form_config.yaml`

```
pics:
    label: Your Pics
    type: myCustomewidget
    ... options
```

and you can reuse it, as well you can add your `js`, `css` and `partials(html)` separately dedicated to widget as you wish